# Why would I want someone to leave my town?

Tags: dragon-quest-vii

In Dragon Quest 7, you can recruit reformed monsters to inhabit a town called *The Haven*. The town is administered by a young lady named Carey... and speaking with her provides the dialogue option to ask a resident to leave.

Why would I want to do this?

Comment: I've heard about this back in the Playstation 1 version. However I heard that to avoid some hassles, the 3DS version simply went with a version of the Immigrant Town/Haven that simply had *all* of the features of the old one? I could be wrong, but the wiki still seem to house some obsolete informations... like the "essential/unchangeable" NPCs that are currently not in the 3DS version(like the trader) that seem to include none of the current essentials of the 3DS version(like the slime prince/etc)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the information provided in [The Haven wikia](http://dragonquest.wikia.com/wiki/The_Haven), it looks like the type of town The Haven turns into is based on what types of monsters live in your town.

> After 35 immigrants move in, the town turns into one of five towns, depending on the type of immigrants.
>
> - Normal Town - The normal town will most likely be the first town that the player creates. It has a mix of different types of immigrants. This final form has a ? Shard.
> - Farm - This town will come to be if the player recruits mostly farmers and animals. It is a farming collective. The only use to this town is to get Gabo's ultimate weapon, the Oricon Claws.
> - Cathedral - This town will come to be if the player recruits mostly priests and nuns. It is one giant church. It will have mostly holy type items in their stores.
> - Bazaar - This town will come to be if the player recruits mostly merchants and traders. This town sells both the Metal King Sword and the Metal King Shield. For those looking to equip their party with the best weapons and armor in the game, this town is essential.
> - Slum - This town will come to be if the player recruits dancers, bullies and the like. It holds a casino that which has all of the games that the game provides. The prizes include the Metal King Armor.

Based on the information provided, it doesn't seem like you will be able to change the type of town The Haven turns into once it has changed, so if you are wanting a specific type of town, you may want to remove ... *undesirables*.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to do some digging into the wiki entry as I don't seem to have any choice about who I bring in right now - each island seems to have a representative who breadcrumbs me to the next.